# get terminal cursor position

Tags: c, ncurses

i need to get the terminal cursor position then set it, i already know how to set it using "move", that's in ncurses, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [`getyx()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_getyx)?

Or, if you prefer legacy curses functions, [getcurx() and getcury()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_legacy)?

Comment: Curses isn't always good, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/a/654492/257568. Here are pointers to a more direct way: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-cursor-position-in-c-947833/#post4693254