# How can I read one character from stdin without having to hit enter?

Tags: rust

I want to run an executable that blocks on stdin and when a key is pressed that same character is printed immediately without <kbd>Enter</kbd> having to be pressed.

How can I read one character from stdin without having to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>? I started with this example:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Type something!");

    let mut line = String::new();
    let input = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("{}", input);
}
```

I looked through the API and tried replacing `read_line()` with `bytes()`, but everything I try requires me to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before read occurs.

This question was asked for C/C++, but there seems to be no standard way to do it: [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

It might not be doable in Rust considering it's not simple in C/C++.

Comment: This is a platform issue, not a language one.  On windows there are character input functions, but on unix/linux you have to take the terminal out of line buffered mode.

Comment: You can use the `getch` function from the mentioned SO link. You just have to compile that into a shared object, and use it from Rust: https://gist.github.com/ihrwein/a4558d63d9250ee0bbf6 You will need a C compiler and it works only on Linux (at least I tested it there).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use one of the 'ncurses' libraries now available, for instance [this](https://crates.io/crates/ncurses) one.

Add the dependency in Cargo

```
[dependencies]
ncurses = "5.86.0"
```

and include in main.rs:

```
extern crate ncurses;
use ncurses::*; // watch for globs
```

Follow the examples in the library to initialize ncurses and wait for single character input like this:

```
initscr();
/* Print to the back buffer. */
printw("Hello, world!");

/* Update the screen. */
refresh();

/* Wait for a key press. */
getch();

/* Terminate ncurses. */
endwin();
```

Comment: This works, but it seems it is impossible to avoid clearing the screen which is enforced by `initscr()` as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772061/curses-library-c-getch-without-clearing-screen) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654471/ncurses-initialization-without-clearing-the-screen).

Comment: Note that ncurses only works on Unix systems, use [pancurses](https://github.com/ihalila/pancurses) if you need cross platform support for Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 20):

While @Jon's solution using ncurses works, ncurses clears the screen by design. I came up with this solution that uses the [termios crate](https://crates.io/crates/termios) for my little project to learn Rust. The idea is to modify `ECHO` and `ICANON` flags by accessing `tcsetattr` through termios bindings.

```
extern crate termios;
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use termios::{Termios, TCSANOW, ECHO, ICANON, tcsetattr};

fn main() {
    let stdin = 0; // couldn't get std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd to work 
                   // on /dev/stdin or /dev/tty
    let termios = Termios::from_fd(stdin).unwrap();
    let mut new_termios = termios.clone();  // make a mutable copy of termios 
                                            // that we will modify
    new_termios.c_lflag &= !(ICANON | ECHO); // no echo and canonical mode
    tcsetattr(stdin, TCSANOW, &mut new_termios).unwrap();
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer = [0;1];  // read exactly one byte
    print!("Hit a key! ");
    stdout.lock().flush().unwrap();
    reader.read_exact(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("You have hit: {:?}", buffer);
    tcsetattr(stdin, TCSANOW, & termios).unwrap();  // reset the stdin to 
                                                    // original termios data
}
```

One advantage of reading a single byte is capturing arrow keys, ctrl etc. Extended F-keys are not captured (although ncurses can capture these).

This solution is intended for UNIX-like platforms. I have no experience with Windows, but according to this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2t3sg9/password_input_on_stdin/) perhaps something similar can be achieved using `SetConsoleMode` in Windows.

Comment: You can use `libc::STDIN_FILENO` defined in the `libc` crate instead of defining `stdin` yourself.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use [termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion), but you will have to enable the [raw TTY mode](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.2/termion/raw/index.html) which changes the behavior of `stdout` as well. See the example below (tested with Rust 1.34.0). Note that internally, it also wraps the termios UNIX API.

#### Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
termion = "1.5.2"
```

#### main.rs

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::thread;
use std::time;

use termion;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;

fn main() {
    // Set terminal to raw mode to allow reading stdin one key at a time
    let mut stdout = io::stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    // Use asynchronous stdin
    let mut stdin = termion::async_stdin().keys();

    loop {
        // Read input (if any)
        let input = stdin.next();

        // If a key was pressed
        if let Some(Ok(key)) = input {
            match key {
                // Exit if 'q' is pressed
                termion::event::Key::Char('q') => break,
                // Else print the pressed key
                _ => {
                    write!(
                        stdout,
                        "{}{}Key pressed: {:?}",
                        termion::clear::All,
                        termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
                        key
                    )
                    .unwrap();

                    stdout.lock().flush().unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly termion doesn't support windows, it won't even compile on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lightweight solution only using the `libc` crate based [some code from the `console` crate](https://docs.rs/console/0.15.0/src/console/unix_term.rs.html#150):

```
fn setup_raw_terminal() -> io::Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let tty;
        let fd = if libc::isatty(libc::STDIN_FILENO) == 1 {
            libc::STDIN_FILENO
        } else {
            tty = fs::File::open("/dev/tty")?;

            tty.as_raw_fd()
        };

        let mut ptr = core::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();

        if libc::tcgetattr(fd, ptr.as_mut_ptr()) == 0 {
            let mut termios = ptr.assume_init();
            let c_oflag = termios.c_oflag;

            libc::cfmakeraw(&mut termios);
            termios.c_oflag = c_oflag;

            if libc::tcsetattr(fd, libc::TCSADRAIN, &termios) == 0 {
                return Ok(());
            }
        }
    }

    Err(io::Error::last_os_error())
}
```

It needs to be called before reading stdin:

```
let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
let mut stdin = io::stdin();

setup_raw_terminal()?;

loop {
    let size = stdin.read(&mut buf)?;
    let data = &buf[0..size];

    println!("stdin data: {}", data);
}
```