# How do I get keyboard input without the user pressing the Enter key?

Tags: rust

I would use ncurses but I want it to run on Windows. In C++, I could use `kbhit()` and `getch()` from conio to first check if a character was pressed, then get it.

I would like something similar in Rust.

Comment: FFI to `kbhit()` and `getch()`?

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь do you have any good tutorials on that?

Comment: The [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) does

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/geofft/demo-rust-getch  You probably don't need to do the FFI stuff by yourself. Look at the `nix` crate for example.

Comment: See also [How can I read one character from stdin without having to hit enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26321592/155423)

Answer (score 8):

With the crate [device_query](https://docs.rs/device_query/) you can query the keyboard state without requiring an active window. You just need to add in your `Cargo.toml` file the dependency to this crate:

```
[dependencies]
device_query = "0.1.0"
```

The usage is straightforward and similar to `kbhit()` and `getch()`. The difference is you'll receive a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) of pressed keys ([`Keycode`](https://docs.rs/device_query/0.1.0/device_query/keymap/enum.Keycode.html)) and this `Vec` will be empty if no key is pressed. A single call covers the functionality of both `kbhit()` and `getch()` combined.

```
use device_query::{DeviceQuery, DeviceState, Keycode};

fn main() {
    let device_state = DeviceState::new();
    loop {
        let keys: Vec<Keycode> = device_state.get_keys();
        for key in keys.iter() {
            println!("Pressed key: {:?}", key);
        }
    }
}
```

This program will print out all pressed keys on the console. To instead just check if any key is pressed (like with `kbhit()` only), you could use `is_empty()` on the returned `Vec<>` like this:

```
let keys: Vec<Keycode> = device_state.get_keys();
if !keys.is_empty(){
    println!("kbhit");
}
```

Comment: it seems that method `get_keys()`  is non-blocking , it will return immediately ， so the main program keep polling ?

Comment: This method no longer works.  I have tried the version in question (after using cargo add device_query, witch panicked with an error about how I do not have an X display).  Then I ran cargo clean, wiped the lock file, and switched the version to 0.1.0, and I got a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You still can do something like

```rust
extern {
    fn _getch() -> core::ffi::c_char;
}

fn getch() -> char {
    unsafe {
        _getch() as char
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keyboard events in rust without pressing enter
adding as a development dependency to k_board a lightweight crate developed with the purpose of offering a listener to the keyboard in raw mode using low-level resources (it does not have dependencies like other crates), I attach how you could capture any letter from the keyboard

`cargo add k_board`

```rust
use k_board::{keyboard::Keyboard, keys::Keys};

fn main() {
    println!("[*] I use k_board lightweight software");
    println!("[ ] I use heavyweight software");
    for key in Keyboard::new() {
        match key {
            Keys::Up => {
                std::process::Command::new("clear").status().unwrap();
                println!("[*] I use k_board lightweight software");
                println!("[ ] I use heavyweight software");
            }
            Keys::Down => {
                std::process::Command::new("clear").status().unwrap();
                println!("[ ] I use k_board lightweight software");
                println!("[*] I use heavyweight software");
            }
            Keys::Enter => {
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Here I attach the list of keys and events

```rust
pub enum Keys {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
    Enter,
    Space,
    Delete,
    Escape,
    Char(char)
    F(u8),
    Ctrl(char),
    Alt(char),
    AltGr(char),
    Null,
}
```

Considering that **efficiency** in code is vital for developing a high-performance program, you can choose which parts of the keyboard will be listened to during runtime. If you only want to use the arrow keys and enter for your program, you can simply add it to your repository without features. However, if you want to use letters, numbers, special combinations, then you'll have to add it as a **feature**.