# How can I get a single byte from stdin in Rust without waiting for Enter?

Tags: rust, byte, stdin

I have a background thread that reads bytes in an infinite loop and sends them to main through a `channel`. I'm looking for the equivalent of C's `getch()`.

I found this:

```
let byte = io::stdin().bytes().next().expect("no byte read").ok().unwrap();
```

This waits for an <kbd>Enter</kbd> which I don't want. It also prints the inputted character, which is also unwanted.

After I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get all the characters I pressed one by one and finally instead of just a 10 (new line), I get 10 followed by 13. Why?

Comment: Isn't waiting for keyboard input and echoing the character something that already happens in `getche`? Are you sure that you want an equivalent to this function?

Comment: You also seem to have some misconceptions: 12 is the character code for new page, not new line (10). And you are likely in a windows system, which produces the CR+LF combination on enter. In another side note, you can call `unwrap` on a `Result`, you don't have to call `ok` beforehand.

Comment: @E_net4 Oops I meant `getch()`. I do want to wait for keyboard input but I don't want to print it.

Comment: `getch()` is not standard in C, but it's come from ncurses lib. You want a crate that handle terminal I/O. https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs, https://github.com/ihalila/pancurses, https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive, etc...

Comment: @Stargateur I see how I can use ncurses but isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: @Neo When I look, what you ask: "it waits for an enter which I don't want", https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013230/7076153, "It also prints the inputted char, which is also unwanted", clearly std will not handle that, this is about terminal configuration. By the way, ASCII code 13 is just a `'\r'`, read about line break in windows.

Comment: @Stargateur This exact answer is the reason I do it in a different thread. I don't mind blocking (until any char is typed), but I don't want it to wait for an **enter**. Isn't that possible? Also about printing, I prefer it not to print but if it's inevitable I can live with it. (However I'm 100% sure it's technically possible as `getch()` does it.)

Comment: @Neo the answer to without press enter is again ncurses, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321592/how-can-i-read-one-character-from-stdin-without-having-to-hit-enter, please learn to search a little !